# Having problem with SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql

I have this below soql query in one batch class start method. Even if I run the batch class with the below-matching query, I am not getting anything. I have few records with this condition but not getting anything even I run the Batch. I think something problem with this query. Can anyone correct this query, please?

```
  String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Account_Type__c, ' 
                    +'(SELECT Id, Name, Account__c, Application_Status__c, Training_Requirements_Met__c, Training_Override__c, Level__r.Name , Partner_Type__r.Name , Solution_Type__r.Name FROM Accreditations__r WHERE Application_Status__c = \'Legal Approved/Awaiting Training Completion\' OR Application_Status__c = \'Partner Agreement Accepted\' ),' 
                    +'(SELECT Id, Account__c, Active__c, Student_Id__c, Training_Course__r.Name, Expiration_Date__c FROM Certifications__r ORDER BY Student_Id__c)'
                    +'FROM Account WHERE Account_Type__c includes (\'Channel\')';
    system.debug('========='+ query);
```

Comment: Have you executed this query in developer console?

Comment: are you getting any exception. Check the apex job page for details.

Comment: Are you running the batch with the same User who runs the SOQL Query ?

Comment: Yes, I executed In developer console. It says "Unknown error parsing query", And Yes, I am running the batch with the same user who runs the query

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check what the query returns is to run it in the [Developer Console Query Editor](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_tab_query_editor.htm&type=0). You can then quickly add and remove `where` terms to isolate where the problem is.

You do not need to use dynamic SOQL in a batch class. Using static SOQL allows the compiler to check your query (so you find mistakes earlier) and avoids you having to add escape characters and quotes so the query a little easier to read:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT
            Id, Name, Account_Type__c,
            (
                SELECT Id, Name, Account__c, Application_Status__c, Training_Requirements_Met__c, Training_Override__c, Level__r.Name, Partner_Type__r.Name, Solution_Type__r.Name
                FROM Accreditations__r
                WHERE Application_Status__c = 'Legal Approved/Awaiting Training Completion'
                OR Application_Status__c = 'Partner Agreement Accepted'
            ),
            (
                SELECT Id, Account__c, Active__c, Student_Id__c, Training_Course__r.Name, Expiration_Date__c
                FROM Certifications__r
                ORDER BY Student_Id__c
            )
        FROM Account
        WHERE Account_Type__c includes ('Channel')
    ]);
}
```